# Syntax for MySQL trying to update a MySql table, however syntax is off

Tags: java, html, mysql

Currently this is my code to update my sql, and I'm getting a syntax error. the carid is being passed in from the front end. Can anyone assist me with fixing the syntax.

```
String carid = req.getParameter("id");

int rs;
Connection conn = null;
java.sql.PreparedStatement st= null;
String nativeSQL = "";

try {
    Context    ctx = new InitialContext();
    Context env = ( Context )ctx.lookup( "java:comp/env" );
    DataSource ds = ( DataSource )env.lookup( "jdbc/carRentalSystem");
    conn = ds.getConnection();

    st = conn.prepareStatement("update cardetails SET Availability = Unavailable where id='"+ carid+ "'");
    st.clearParameters();
    rs= st.executeUpdate();
            if(rs != 0) {
                res.sendRedirect("carRental.jsp");
                return;
            }else {

            }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    finally {
        try{ if(st != null ) st.close(); } catch(java.sql.SQLException e){}
        try{ if(conn != null ) conn.close(); } catch(java.sql.SQLException e){}

    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get it and what is it?

Comment: id is is an in that is being queryed on the jsp from the same table and Availability is an enum that is with Available or Unavailable

Comment: I meant what the syntax error is, never mind, I see that you got your answer even without posting it. Please post the errors you get with your question next time.

Comment: Use a PreparedStatement - see [SQL Injection attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the sql query line to

```
 st = conn.prepareStatement("update cardetails SET Availability = 'Unavailable' where id='"+ carid+ "'");
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Strings should be wrapped with quotes :

```
"update cardetails SET Availability = 'Unavailable' where id='"+ carid+ "'"
```